# Difference between git commit --amend and git rebase under gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I want to change the last commit content.
I can do local changes.
and then execute

```
git commit --amend
```

I can also do the following:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~
```

choose the commit to edit.
do local changes
and then execute:

```
git rebase --continue
```

1. is there a difference between these two commands in this scenario ?
2. in the context of Gerrit, when gerrit's CHANGE-ID is involved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. They both use the previous commit as a template to generate a new commit. The Gerrit change-id is simply tracked by the line in the commit comment so provided you don't modify or remove that line Gerrit can still track this new commit as referring to that change.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have 3 commits A->B->C, and you have change a file which is included in commit A, so, you should make commit A at the top

```
git stash /* to save your changes */

git rebase -i HEAD~3
move commit A at the bottom of commits B&C
save&exit
```

if you make

```
git log
```

you wil have this sequence B->C->A, you make

```
git add /*your changed file*/
git commit --amend
```

now you must return commit A back to not change gerrit dependencies list

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
move commit A at the top of commit B&C
save&exit
```

now if you push to gerrit, you will have the same old order